2020 M1 Macbook Air having random CPU spikes when using browser
I've noticed that every few minutes my CPU spikes to a 100% (sometimes even higher) whenever I'm using my browser. This happens randomly, but it usually happens when I'm trying to click on something which causes my whole laptop to freeze for a few seconds. It seems to still spike even after I try restarting or changing browsers.
I have absolutely no idea why this happens.
macOS Sonoma 14.1.1, 2020 M1 Macbook Air, currently using Brave as my main browser.

^Just an example of the CPU spike that I managed to screenshot, usually it lasts even longer than this.

I would leave Activity Monitor open in the background all the time, and see if you can switch to it when it happens, and look for what processes are hogging the CPU.

@benwiggy Thanks for your comment! I checked Activity Monitor when there was a spike but it seems to be mostly normal. The process that was using the most CPU were usually my browser, WindowServer, or kernel_task. Brave seems to be using a hell lot of helpers (Brave Browser Helper (Renderer), sometimes even up to 15 at a time, is that normal?

And you get the same behaviour when using Safari, FireFox, Vivaldi, or Edge?  -- (Don't use Chrome.)

Yep. I've already tried changing browsers.

If it's doing it regardless of the browser, then it might be unrelated to browsing, but something else. Does the problem occur in a brand new user account? (This is a test, not a solution!)

Actually, after reading your previous post, I realized that I had the same extension across all the browsers that I tested, and after uninstalling it, the issue seems to have been fixed, Thank you!
